# Accidently moved /usr/lib64 how can I restore

Tags: mv, shared-library, system-recovery

I was trying to free up space and clueless moved /usr/lib64/ to "/srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64". The next thing I was going to do is create a symlink in usr for lib64 to point to /srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64 but quickly stumbled upon issues with ELF.

My biggest problem is I was using sudo to do all of this. I figured out based on other posts how to issue commands, and can do:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64 /srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/echo a
a
bash: /usr/bin/basename: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However to restore /usr/lib64 I need root privileges. I tried sudo but it's a fail:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64 /srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/ln -s /srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64 lib64
/usr/bin/sudo: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
bash: /usr/bin/basename: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I try su I get an error as well:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64 /srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/su root
su: Module is unknown
bash: /usr/bin/basename: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I believe the su error may be related to my /etc/pam.d/su file:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth       sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth        substack    system-auth
auth        include     postlogin
account     sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account     include     system-auth
password    include     system-auth
session     include     system-auth
session     include     postlogin
session     optional    pam_xauth.so
bash: /usr/bin/basename: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

pam_rootok.so is in the moved lib64 dir.

Aside from a boot using a live disk, does anyone else have any ideas? I don't have busybox.

P.S. should mention I have GUI through vncserver. Is there anyway to invoke root commands from GUI? CentOS 7, Gnome2.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to boot using a live disk? That will likely be the easiest solution.

Comment: Server has no CD reader, will likely need to boot from a USB, will take a while for me to figure it out and only going to work tomorrow. Wanted to get some stuff done from home today.

Comment: AS this is a physical machine, what brand of server is it? If it's Dell then you can use Drac to boot from a live ISO image of any Linux Distro and move `/usr/lib64` back into place.

Comment: OK, although I haven't booted from a CD in at least 10 years. USB is the standard way. By the way, I think the command you want to try is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64 /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/ln -s /srv/maraba_ssd_scratch/apelin/root_files/usr_lib64 lib64`, you don't want the second path there. As you can see from the error message, it is being interpreted as a command.